# Using foldr when the base case is an error

Tags: racket, lazy-evaluation

I am wondering how you would convert this function to foldr. Particularly the base case, which is an error. The parameters are a list and an element of the list. The function just counts the number of elements to the element in the parameter (x).

```
; [List-of X] X -> number or error
; Count number of elements to X
(define (cnt l x)
  (cond
    [(empty? l) (error x "not found")]
    [(symbol=? (first l) x) 0]
    [else (add1 (cnt (rest l) x))]))
```

Comment: In normal racket, I'm pretty sure it's impossible. However, if you use `#lang lazy` in DrRacket it might be possible, I'll try that.

Comment: Ok, it's possible in normal racket, though it requires extra `lambda`s and zero-argument function applications in weird places. Using `#lang lazy`, you can write this the normal way.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible in the obvious way in normal strict racket, but it is possible if you put [`#lang lazy`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/lazy/index.html) at the top of your DrRacket file:

```
#lang lazy

; [List-of X] X -> number or error
; Count number of elements to X
(define (cnt l x)
  (foldr (lambda (y cnt-rest)
           (cond [(symbol=? y x) 0]
                 [else (add1 cnt-rest)]))
         (error x "not found")
         l))
```

Using it:

```
> (cnt (list) 'a)
a: not found
> (cnt (list 'a) 'a)
0
> (cnt (list 'a 'b 'c) 'a)
0
> (cnt (list 'a 'b 'c) 'b)
1
> (cnt (list 'a 'b 'c) 'c)
2
> (cnt (list 'a 'b 'c) 'd)
d: not found
> (cnt (list 'a 'b 'c 'b 'a 'b 'c) 'c)
2
```

It's also possible to do this in normal racket by wrapping things in [`lambda`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/lambda.html) expressions and zero-argument function applications in just the right combination of ways:

```
#lang racket

; [List-of X] X -> number or error
; Count number of elements to X
(define (cnt l x)
  ((foldr (lambda (y cnt-rest)
            (lambda ()
              (cond [(symbol=? y x) 0]
                    [else (add1 (cnt-rest))])))
          (lambda ()
            (error x "not found"))
          l)))
```

Though this can be is very tricky and hard to understand. You can also express this in another way using [`delay`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Delayed_Evaluation.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fpromise..rkt%29._delay%29%29) and [`force`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Delayed_Evaluation.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fpromise..rkt%29._force%29%29) from [`racket/promise`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Delayed_Evaluation.html):

```
#lang racket

; [List-of X] X -> number or error
; Count number of elements to X
(define (cnt l x)
  (force (foldr (lambda (y cnt-rest)
                  (delay
                    (cond [(symbol=? y x) 0]
                          [else (add1 (force cnt-rest))])))
                (delay
                  (error x "not found"))
                l)))
```

The [`delay`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Delayed_Evaluation.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fpromise..rkt%29._delay%29%29) forms go where the extra [`lambda`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/lambda.html)s had been, and the [`force`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Delayed_Evaluation.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fpromise..rkt%29._force%29%29) calls go where the extra zero-argument function calls had been. The [`#lang lazy`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/lazy/index.html) language puts these [`delay`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Delayed_Evaluation.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fpromise..rkt%29._delay%29%29)s and [`force`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Delayed_Evaluation.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fpromise..rkt%29._force%29%29)s there for you, so that's why

```
#lang lazy

; [List-of X] X -> number or error
; Count number of elements to X
(define (cnt l x)
  (foldr (lambda (y cnt-rest)
           (cond [(symbol=? y x) 0]
                 [else (add1 cnt-rest)]))
         (error x "not found")
         l))
```

Worked before. It added [`delay`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Delayed_Evaluation.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fpromise..rkt%29._delay%29%29)s and [`force`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Delayed_Evaluation.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fpromise..rkt%29._force%29%29)s everywhere. And, each [`delay`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Delayed_Evaluation.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fpromise..rkt%29._delay%29%29) form is like adding an extra [`lambda`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/lambda.html) (plus other stuff), and each [`force`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Delayed_Evaluation.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fpromise..rkt%29._force%29%29) call is like adding an extra zero-argument function call (plus other stuff).

Comment: Thanks for that. I think I will just stay with the original version as it is easier to understand and just as concise as the foldr version.

Comment: Yes. The original version is definitely easier to understand.